# How to organize large R programs?

Tags: r, package, conventions, code-organization, project-organization

When I undertake an R project of any complexity, my scripts quickly get long and confusing.

What are some practices I can adopt so that my code will always be a pleasure to work with? I'm thinking about things like

- Placement of functions in source files
- When to break something out to another source file
- What should be in the master file
- Using functions as organizational units (whether this is worthwhile given that R makes it hard to access global state)
- Indentation / line break practices.

  - Treat ( like {?
  - Put things like )} on 1 or 2 lines?

Basically, what are your rules of thumb for organizing large R scripts?

Comment: You may also want to look at the `ProjectTemplate` package.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The standard answer is to use packages -- see the [Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.pdf) manual as well as different tutorials on the web.

It gives you

- a quasi-automatic way to organize your code by topic
- strongly encourages you to write a help file, making you think about the interface
- a lot of sanity checks via `R CMD check`
- a chance to add regression tests
- as well as a means for namespaces.

Just running `source()` over code works for really short snippets. Everything else should be in a package -- even if you do not plan to publish it as you can write internal packages for internal repositories.

As for the 'how to edit' part, the [R Internals](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-ints.html) manual has excellent *R coding standards* in Section 6.  Otherwise, I tend to use defaults in [Emacs' ESS mode](http://ess.r-project.org/).

*Update 2008-Aug-13:*  David Smith just blogged about the [Google R Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/Rguide.xml).

Comment: If you're growing your source-tree/analysis "organically," don't you find this hard to do/cumbersome? If you notice a mistake in your code (common while exploring a new problem space), you have to (i) fix source; (ii) reinstall package; (iii) reload it into your workspace?

Is there a way to call library(...) in order to reload a package that's already loaded (step iii above)? Don't you have to kill your workspace, restart R then reload your library/package in order to see if it's right?

Comment: Dirk, are you aware of any coding style guidelines similar to the Python PEP: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/  ...  I've read the coding standards you mentioned, and they cover slightly different ground.  I thought I'd ask since you seem pretty knowledgable and I've never managed to come across anything similar in R.  Thanks.

Comment: Trying googling for R coding style.

Comment: @hadley: I could have been clearer; I meant something roughly analogous to a python PEP: an official/semi-offical R document like the one linked to by Dirk.  Perhaps I'm missing something obvious here.  Thanks though.

Comment: Ars, the manuals by R Core are as formal as it gets. The rest is contributed as e.g. Henrik's RCC.

Comment: @SteveLianoglou I know this is quite old but Hadley's devtools package makes reloading all of your code very easy.

Comment: This blog post gives a (my opinion) really good quick tutorial to build a bare bones first package: http://hilaryparker.com/2014/04/29/writing-an-r-package-from-scratch/

Comment: Here is working link to [Google R Style Guide](http://google.github.io/styleguide/Rguide.xml)

Comment: "You could but it does not mean you should."  For a research-lab internal, or company internal, package 1gb data inside the package may be _perfectly valid and reasonable_.  In practice you cannot have such a package on GitHub (exceeds large file requirements) or CRAN.  But there is _no R-specific reason why you cannot_ even if there are other, related, but not driven by R, reasons why you should not.  Lastly, we have a paper in  the R Journal about how to cope with 'larger than usual' data packages completing R code packages.

Comment: while packages in R definitely help organizing namespaces of functions, they have nothing to do with organizing complex data structures and data encapsulation, either...

Comment: "Opinions vary."  Talk to a number of different (experienced) R users and you _will_ find many using packages to organize, wrap, test (!!), document, and ship data sets.  BioConductor has entire sub-repos for it.  `install.packages()` and `'update.packages()` are powerful and can help with (some) data problems. Nobody claimed this replaces SQL but a package improves (vastly) over a single csv to zip file somewhere.

Answer (score 55):

I like putting different functionality in their own files.

But I don't like R's package system.  It's rather hard to use.

I prefer a lightweight alternative, to place a file's functions inside an environment (what every other language calls a "namespace") and attach it.  For example, I made a 'util' group of functions like so:

```
util = new.env()

util$bgrep = function [...]

util$timeit = function [...]

while("util" %in% search())
  detach("util")
attach(util)
```

This is all in a file [util.R](http://github.com/brendano/dlanalysis/tree/master/util.R).  When you source it, you get the environment 'util' so you can call `util$bgrep()` and such; but furthermore, the `attach()` call makes it so just `bgrep()` and such work directly.  If you didn't put all those functions in their own environment, they'd pollute the interpreter's top-level namespace (the one that `ls()` shows).

I was trying to simulate Python's system, where every file is a module.  That would be better to have, but this seems OK.

Comment: Thanks, Brendan. That is very useful. What is up with the while loop? What is wrong with if (!("util" %in% search())) attach(util)

Comment: so you can do source("util.R") again and again if you want to tweak it and such.

Comment: you don't need a while loop really -- all you need it detach(util).  i can't remember if it gives an error or not if it's not already loaded, but this is safest and does work.  suggestions welcome.

Comment: Creating functions-specific environments and attaching it is the way to go for me. Another method to achieve the same thing in a different way (with more modularity) is to use `sys.source`:
`MyEnv <- attach(NULL, name=s_env); 
  sys.source(file, MyEnv)`. I even declare (in its own environment!) at start-up a function `sys.source2` which will look up if an environment of the same name is already here and feeds this one instead of creating a new one. It makes adding personal functions quick, easy and kinda organized :-)

Comment: Just saw this today and it applies to a package alternative: https://github.com/klmr/modules

Comment: But what if I have two source files with the same function or variable names? Attaching them together will causes name collision. Using `attach` is bad idea.

Answer (score 34):

This might sound a little obvious especially if you're a programmer, but here's how I think about logical and physical units of code.

I don't know if this is your case, but when I'm working in R, I rarely start out with a large complex program in mind.   I usually start in one script and separate code into logically separable units, often using functions.  Data manipulation and visualization code get placed in their own functions, etc.  And such functions are grouped together in one section of the file (data manipulation at the top, then visualization, etc).  Ultimately you want to think about how to make it easier for you to maintain your script and lower the defect rate.

How fine/coarse grained you make your functions will vary and there are various rules of thumb: e.g. 15 lines of code, or "a function should be responsible for doing one task which is identified by its name", etc.  Your mileage will vary.  Since R doesn't support call-by-reference, I'm usually vary of making my functions too fine grained when it involves passing data frames or similar structures around.  But this may be overcompensation for some silly performance mistakes when I first started out with R.

When to extract logical units into their own physical units (like source files and bigger groupings like packages)?  I have two cases.  First, if the file gets too large and scrolling around among logically unrelated units is an annoyance.  Second, if I have functions that can be reused by other programs.  I usually start out by placing some grouped unit, say data manipulation functions, into a separate file.  I can then source this file from any other script.

If you're going to deploy your functions, then you need to start thinking about packages.  I don't deploy R code in production or for re-use by others for various reasons (briefly: org culture prefers other langauges, concerns about performance, GPL, etc).  Also, I tend to constantly refine and add to my collections of sourced files, and I'd rather not deal with packages when I make a change.  So you should check out the other package related answers, like Dirk's, for more details on this front.

Finally, I think your question isn't necessarily particular to R.  I would really recommend reading Code Complete by Steve McConnell which contains a lot of wisdom about such issues and coding practices at large.

Answer (score 17):

My concise answer:

1. Write your functions carefully, identifying general enough outputs and inputs;
2. Limit the use of global variables;
3. Use S3 objects and, where appropriate, S4 objects;
4. Put the functions in packages, especially when your functions are calling C/Fortran.

I believe R is more and more used in production, so the need for reusable code is greater than before. I find the interpreter much more robust  than before. There is no doubt that R is 100-300x slower than C, but usually the bottleneck is concentrated around a few lines of code, which can be delegated to C/C++. I think it would be a mistake to delegate the strengths of R in data manipulation and statistical analysis to another language. In these instances, the performance penalty is low, and in any case well worth the savings in development effort. If execution time alone were the matter, we'd be all writing assembler.

Answer (score 11):

I've been meaning to figure out how to write packages but haven't invested the time. For each of my mini-projects I keep all of my low-level functions in a folder called 'functions/', and source them into a separate namespace that I explicitly create.

The following lines of code will create an environment named "myfuncs" on the search path if it doesn't already exist (using attach), and populate it with the functions contained in the .r files in my 'functions/' directory (using sys.source). I usually put these lines at the top of my main script meant for the "user interface" from which high-level functions (invoking the low-level functions) are called.

```
if( length(grep("^myfuncs$",search()))==0 )
  attach("myfuncs",pos=2)
for( f in list.files("functions","\\.r$",full=TRUE) )
  sys.source(f,pos.to.env(grep("^myfuncs$",search())))
```

When you make changes you can always re-source it with the same lines, or use something like

```
evalq(f <- function(x) x * 2, pos.to.env(grep("^myfuncs$",search())))
```

to evaluate additions/modifications in the environment you created.

It's kludgey I know, but avoids having to be too formal about it (but if you get the chance I do encourage the package system - hopefully I will migrate that way in the future).

As for coding conventions, this is the only thing I've seen regarding aesthetics (I like them and loosely follow but I don't use too many curly braces in R):

http://www1.maths.lth.se/help/R/RCC/

There are other "conventions" regarding the use of [,drop=FALSE] and <- as the assignment operator suggested in various presentations (usually keynote) at the useR! conferences, but I don't think any of these are strict (though the [,drop=FALSE] is useful for programs in which you are not sure of the input you expect).

Answer (score 6):

Count me as another person in favor of packages.  I'll admit to being pretty poor on writing man pages and vignettes until if/when I have to (ie being released), but it makes for a real handy way to bundle source doe.  Plus, if you get serious about maintaining your code, the points that Dirk brings up all come into plya.

Answer (score 4):

I also agree. Use the package.skeleton() function to get started.  Even if you think your code may never be run again, it may help motivate you to create more general code that could save you time later.

As for accessing the global environment, that is easy with the <<- operator, though it is discouraged.

Answer (score 3):

Having not learned how to write packages yet, I have always organized by sourcing sub scripts. Its similar to writing classes but not as involved. Its not programatically elegant but I find I build up analyses over time. Once I have a big section that works I often move it to a different script and just source it since it will use the workspace objects. Perhaps I need to import data from several sources, sort all of them and find the intersections. I might put that section into an additional script. However, if you want to distribute your "application" for other people, or it uses some interactive input, a package is probably a good route. As a researcher I rarely need to distribute my analysis code but I OFTEN need to augment or tweak it.

Comment: I used this method but have since realized that functions and packages are better than source("next_script.R"). I wrote about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25273166/combine-and-run-multiple-r-scripts-from-another-script/57455236#57455236

Answer (score 2):

I have also been searching for the holy grail of the right workflow for putting together an R large project. Last year, I found this package called [rsuite](https://rsuite.io/), and, certainly, it was what I was looking for. This R package was explicitly developed for deployment of large R projects, but I found that it can be used for smaller, medium size, and large size R projects. I will give links to real-world examples in a minute (below), but first, I want to explain the new paradigm of building R projects with `rsuite`.

Note. I am not the creator or developer of `rsuite`.

1. We have been doing projects all wrong with RStudio; the goal shouldn't be the creation of a project or a package but of a larger scope. In rsuite you create a super-project or master project, which holds the standard R projects and R packages, in all combinations possible.
2. By having an R super-project you don't need anymore Unix `make` to manage the lower levels of the R projects underneath; you use R scripts at the top. Let me show you. When you create a rsuite master project, you get this folder structure:

[image]

3. The folder `R` is where you put your project management scripts, the ones that will replace `make`.
4. The folder `packages` is the folder where `rsuite` holds all the packages that compose the super-project. You can also copy paste a package that is not accessible from the internet, and rsuite will build it as well.
5. the folder `deployment` is where `rsuite` will write all the package binaries that were indicated in the packages `DESCRIPTION` files. So, this makes, by itself, you project totally reproducible accros time.
6. `rsuite` comes with a client for all operating systems. I have tested them all. But you can also install it as an `addin` for RStudio.
7. `rsuite` also lets you build an isolated `conda` installation in its own folder `conda`. This is not an environment but a physical Python installation derived from Anaconda in your machine. This works together with R's `SystemRequirements`, from which you could install all the Python packages you want, from any conda channel you want.
8. You can also create local repositories to pull R packages when you are offline, or want to build the whole thing faster.
9. If you want, you can also build the R project as a zip file and share it with colleagues. It will run, providing your colleagues have the same R version installed.
10. Another option is building a container of the whole project in Ubuntu, Debian, or CentOS. So, instead of sharing a zip file with your project build, you share the whole `Docker` container with your project ready to run.

I have been experimenting a lot with `rsuite` looking for full reproducibility, and avoid depending of the packages that one installs in the global environment. This is wrong because as soon as you install a package update, the project, more often than not, stops working, specially those packages with very specific calls to a function with certain parameters.

The first thing I started to experiment was with `bookdown` ebooks. I have never been lucky enough to have a bookdown to survive the test of time longer than six months. So, what I did is converting the original bookdown project to follow the `rsuite` framework. Now, I don't have to worry about updating my global R environment, because the project has its own set of packages in the `deployment` folder.

The next thing I did was creating machine learning projects but in the `rsuite` way. A master, orchestrating project at the top, and all sub-projects and packages to be under the control of the master. It really changes the way you code with R, making you more productive.

After that I started working in a new package of mine called `rTorch`. This was possible, in large part, because of `rsuite`; it lets you think and  go big.

One piece of advice though. Learning `rsuite` is not easy. Because it presents a new way of creating R projects, it feels hard. Do not dismay at the first attempts, continue climbing the slope until you make it. It requires advanced knowledge of your operating system and of your file system.

I expect that one day `RStudio` allows us to generate orchestrating projects like `rsuite` does from the menu. It would be awesome.

**Links:**

[RSuite GitHUb repo](https://github.com/WLOGSolutions/RSuite)

[r4ds bookdown](https://github.com/f0nzie/r4ds-rsuite)

[keras and shiny tutorial](https://github.com/f0nzie/keras_and_shiny-tutorial)

[moderndive-book-rsuite](https://github.com/f0nzie/moderndive-book-rsuite)

[interpretable_ml-rsuite](https://github.com/f0nzie/interpretable_ml-rsuite)

[IntroMachineLearningWithR-rsuite](https://github.com/f0nzie/IntroMachineLearningWithR-rsuite)

[clark-intro_ml-rsuite](https://github.com/f0nzie/clark-intro_ml-rsuite)

[hyndman-bookdown-rsuite](https://github.com/f0nzie/hyndman-bookdown-rsuite)

[statistical_rethinking-rsuite](https://github.com/f0nzie/statistical_rethinking-rsuite)

[fread-benchmarks-rsuite](https://github.com/f0nzie/fread-benchmarks-rsuite)

[dataviz-rsuite](https://github.com/f0nzie/dataviz-rsuite)

[retail-segmentation-h2o-tutorial](https://github.com/f0nzie/retail-segmentation-h2o-tutorial)

[telco-customer-churn-tutorial](https://github.com/f0nzie/telco-customer-churn-tutorial)

[sclerotinia_rsuite](https://github.com/f0nzie/sclerotinia_rsuite)

Answer (score -4):

R is OK for interactive use and small scripts, but I wouldn't use it for a large program.  I'd use a mainstream language for most of the programming and wrap it in an R interface.

Comment: There are seriously large packages (i.e. programs) out there. Are you seriously suggesting they should be rewritten in some other language? Why???

Comment: One consideration is efficiency. I've often rewritten R code as C++ code and made it 100x faster.  Another is tool support.  R has nothing comparable to IDEs like Eclipse or Visual Studio.  Finally, if a program is very large, it's likely to be doing non-statistical tasks that R is not well suited to.

Comment: There is a plugin (Stat-ET) available that allows Eclipse to interact with R.
I aggree that C++ can work much faster than R. But how much time do you need to recode the R stuff into C++? Unless you can reuse the code frequently, the benefit of the faster code is not worth much compared to the effort to recode it in C++.

Comment: Yes, there's a trade off (productivity v performance).  And for purely data analysis/statistical work, R often wins.  But for writing other tasks, e.g. GUI, web, etc, I'm not sure that's the case.  We often prototype and work in R but deploy production code in Python/C++.  With the latter you get performance *and* very mature and reusable libraries/frameworks for various tasks.  But, this is a fluid situation and the R ecosystem is constantly evolving.

Comment: Using the `Rcpp` package, including C++ code in R programs becomes quite straightforward. So rewriting certain portions of R code can be integrated into R quite easily. In addition, the advent of RStudio has introduced an IDE for R, altough maybe not as powerful as Visual Studio yet.

Comment: That is not correct. R can be used for large application. It is just the tools we know, or at hand, are not proper.

Comment: my personal suggestion is to get used to some sort of intermediate data outputs, such as pivot tables - which you store as a csv file after every function; this may help knowing which data belongs to which task, especially when prototyping your data workflow with large or somewhat bizarre datasets