# Organizing R Source Code

Tags: r

All,

I am starting to write object-oriented R code for the first time and anticipate having multiple R files with dependencies in between.  I'm new to R and have not yet wrote anything outside of a single massive script to test ideas.  Are there resources online that give tips on how one ought to organize code?  Short of descriptions on how to build packages, I'm failing to find such guidance.  At this point, I just want to organize the code in such a way that it makes loading and interacting with the collection of routines as straightforward as possible.

Appreciate any guidance you can provide.

Chris

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266279/how-to-organize-large-r-programs

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This question is very closely related to: ["How to organize large R programs?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266279/how-to-organize-large-r-programs)

You should consider creating an R package.  You can use the `package.skeleton` function to start with given a set of R files.  I also strongly recommend using `roxygen` to document the package at the beginning, because it's much more difficult to do it after the fact.

Read [**"Writing R Extensions"**](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html).  The online book "Statistics with R" has [a section on this subject](http://zoonek2.free.fr/UNIX/48_R/02.html#7).  Also take a look at [Creating R Packages: A Tutorial](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Leisch-CreatingPackages.pdf) by Friedrich Leisch.  Lastly, if you're in NY, come to the upcoming NY use-R group meeting on ["Authoring R Packages: a gentle introduction with examples"](http://www.meetup.com/nyhackr/calendar/12556884/).

Just to rehash some suggestions about good practices:

- A package allows you to use `R CMD check` which is very helpful at catching bugs; separately you can look at using the `codetools` package.
- A package also forces you to do a minimal amount of documentation, which leads to better practices in the long run.
- You should also consider doing unit testing (e.g. with [RUnit](http://cran.r-project.org/package=RUnit)) if you want your code to be robust/maintainable.
- You should consider using a style guide (e.g. [Google Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/Rguide.xml)).
- Use a version control system from the beginning, and if you're going to make your code open source, then consider using github or r-forge.

*Edit:*

Regarding how do make incremental changes without rebuilding and installing the full package: I find the easiest thing to do is to make changes in your relevant R file and then use the `source` command to load those changes.  Once you load your library into an R session, it will always be lower in the environment (and lower in priority) than the .GlobalEnv, so any changes that you source or load in directly will be used first (use the `search` command to see this).  That way you can have your package underlying and you are overwriting changes as you're testing them in the environment.

Alternatively, you can use an IDE like StatET or ESS.  They make loading individual lines or functions out of an R package very easy.  StatET is particularly well designed to handle managing packages in a directory-like structure.

Comment: Thanks Shane.  Exactly the guidance I was looking for.

Comment: So here's another question that came up in the SO discussion you referenced that was unanswered.  As you are modifying / adding code to the developing package, how do you reload the package contents without going through an install?  Is there a convenient way?  Just trying to get a handle on the cycle one is going through as you write code and test.

Comment: Look at the function "sourceDir" which is in the example section of the help file for the "source" function (type "?source" at the R commnand prompt). I have a very similar function in my ~/.Rprofile file, and I sourceDir() the mypackage/R directory of the package I'm building as I make changes to it.

Occasionally I'll reinstall the package, but I find this way easier to make incremental changes w/o blowing away any current work I have going on in the interpreter.

Comment: With the advent of RStudio, reloading R packages has become quite straightforward. Simply select `Build` > `Build and reload` from the menu and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

this is for benefit of others who are directed to this post upon their search.
I too faced exactly same scenario and found no resource which explained it clearly.
Here is my attempt to put the solution in a few simple steps:
1) Create a new project directory
2) Create a Package via R studio(same process as above)
3) Keep both in same location(to avoid confusion).
4) Install and load packages: devtools and and roxygen2.
5) use function load_all().

And you are done.

Comment: what's function ```load_all()```?

Comment: load_all loads a package. It roughly simulates what happens when a package is installed and
loaded with library