# Is there a way to jump to the end of a sourced script without killing entire execution in R?

Tags: r

Suppose I have a script `Foo.r` which looks like this.

```
source('Bar.r')
print("Hello World")
```

Now suppose further that in `Bar.r`, I want to return immediately if some condition is true, instead of executing the rest of the script.

```
if (DO_NOT_RUN_BAR) return; // What should return here be replaced with?
// Remainder of work in bar
```

In particular, if `DO_NOT_RUN_BAR` is set, I want `Bar.r` to return and `Foo.r` to continue execution, printing `Hello World`.

I realize that one way to do this is to invert the `if` statement in `Bar.t` and wrap the entire script inside an `if` statement that checks for the logical negation of `DO_NOT_RUN_BAR`, but I still want to know whether I can replace the `return` statement in the code above to skip execution of the rest of `Bar.r` when it is sourced.

Comment: try stop('some message')

Comment: wrap everything in a function, then call the function after `source`ing. `source('Bar.r');Bar();print('Hello World')`

Answer (score 1):

By defintion , `source` parse a file until the end of the file.
So, I would split bar file in 2 parts :

```
source("bar1.R")
if (DO_RUN_BAR2) source("bar2.R")
print("Hello World")
```

This is safer than managing global variables with dangerous side effect.

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is that if multiple files source  `bar`, `bar` will only get run once. This approach solves that problem but adds the overhead of having additional files for every file that is sourced.

Comment: @merlin2011 I don't get your point here. But maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456501/how-to-include-source-r-script-in-other-scripts) can help you...

Answer (score 1):

In Bar.r you can do

```
if (DO_NOT_RUN_BAR) stop();
```

Then in Foo.r you call it like this

```
try(source("./bar.r"), silent=T)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your script with a multi-line expression with `{...}` enclosing it, and use stop in the middle:

```
{ print("test")
  print("test")
  print("test"); stop()
  print("test")
  print("test")
  print("test") }
#[1] "test"
#[1] "test"
#[1] "test"
#Error:
```