# How to organize large Shiny apps?

Tags: r, shiny

What are the best practices to organize larger Shiny applications?
I think best R practices are also applicable to Shiny.
Best R practices are discussed here: [How to organize large R programs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266279/how-to-organize-large-r-programs?rq=1)
Link to Google's R Style Guide: [Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/Rguide.xml)

But what are the unique tips and tricks in Shiny context which I can adopt to make my Shiny code look better (and more readable)?
I am thinking of things like:

- Exploiting object oriented programming in Shiny
- In `server.R` which parts should be sourced?
- File hierarchy of project containing markdown documents, pictures,
  xml and source files

For example if I am using `navbarPage` and `tabsetPanel` in every `tabPanel` my code is starting to look quite messy after addition of several UI elements.

Example code:

```
server <- function(input, output) {

 #Here functions and outputs..

}

ui <- shinyUI(navbarPage("My Application",
  tabPanel("Component 1",
             sidebarLayout(
                sidebarPanel(
                    # UI elements..
                ),
                mainPanel(
                    tabsetPanel(
                        tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("plot")
                                 # More UI elements..
                                 ), 
                        tabPanel("Summary", verbatimTextOutput("summary")
                                 # And some more...
                                 ), 
                        tabPanel("Table", tableOutput("table")
                                 # And...
                                 )
                    )
                )
    )           
  ),
  tabPanel("Component 2"),
  tabPanel("Component 3")
))

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

For organizing `ui.R` code I found quite nice solution from GitHub: [radiant code](https://github.com/mostly-harmless/radiant/blob/master/dev/marketing/ui.R)
Solution is to use `renderUI` to render every `tabPanel` and in `server.R` tabs are sourced to different files.

```
server <- function(input, output) {

  # This part can be in different source file for example component1.R
  ###################################
  output$component1 <- renderUI({
        sidebarLayout(
                sidebarPanel(
                ),
                mainPanel(
                    tabsetPanel(
                        tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("plot")), 
                        tabPanel("Summary", verbatimTextOutput("summary")), 
                        tabPanel("Table", tableOutput("table"))
                    )
                )
    )
  })
 #####################################  

}
ui <- shinyUI(navbarPage("My Application",
  tabPanel("Component 1", uiOutput("component1")),
  tabPanel("Component 2"),
  tabPanel("Component 3")
))

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

After addition of **modules** to R shiny. Managing of complex structures in shiny applications has become a lot easier.

Detailed description of shiny modules:[Here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html)

> Advantages of using modules:
>
> - Once created, they are easily reused
> - ID collisions is easier to avoid
> - Code organization based on inputs and output of modules

In tab based shiny app, one tab can be considered as one module which has **inputs** and **outputs**. Outputs of tabs can be then passed to other tabs as inputs.

Single-file app for tab-based structure which exploits modular thinking. App can be tested by using [cars](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/datasets/cars.csv) dataset. Parts of the code where copied from the Joe Cheng(first link). All comments are welcome.

```
# Tab module
# This module creates new tab which renders dataTable

dataTabUI <- function(id, input, output) {
  # Create a namespace function using the provided id
  ns <- NS(id)

  tagList(sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(input),

                        mainPanel(dataTableOutput(output))))

}

# Tab module
# This module creates new tab which renders plot
plotTabUI <- function(id, input, output) {
  # Create a namespace function using the provided id
  ns <- NS(id)

  tagList(sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(input),

                        mainPanel(plotOutput(output))))

}

dataTab <- function(input, output, session) {
  # do nothing...
  # Should there be some logic?


}

# File input module
# This module takes as input csv file and outputs dataframe
# Module UI function
csvFileInput <- function(id, label = "CSV file") {
  # Create a namespace function using the provided id
  ns <- NS(id)

  tagList(
    fileInput(ns("file"), label),
    checkboxInput(ns("heading"), "Has heading"),
    selectInput(
      ns("quote"),
      "Quote",
      c(
        "None" = "",
        "Double quote" = "\"",
        "Single quote" = "'"
      )
    )
  )
}

# Module server function
csvFile <- function(input, output, session, stringsAsFactors) {
  # The selected file, if any
  userFile <- reactive({
    # If no file is selected, don't do anything
    validate(need(input$file, message = FALSE))
    input$file
  })

  # The user's data, parsed into a data frame
  dataframe <- reactive({
    read.csv(
      userFile()$datapath,
      header = input$heading,
      quote = input$quote,
      stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors
    )
  })

  # We can run observers in here if we want to
  observe({
    msg <- sprintf("File %s was uploaded", userFile()$name)
    cat(msg, "\n")
  })

  # Return the reactive that yields the data frame
  return(dataframe)
}
basicPlotUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  uiOutput(ns("controls"))

}
# Functionality for dataselection for plot
# SelectInput is rendered dynamically based on data

basicPlot <- function(input, output, session, data) {
  output$controls <- renderUI({
    ns <- session$ns
    selectInput(ns("col"), "Columns", names(data), multiple = TRUE)
  })
  return(reactive({
    validate(need(input$col, FALSE))
    data[, input$col]
  }))
}

##################################################################################
# Here starts main program. Lines above can be sourced: source("path-to-module.R")
##################################################################################

library(shiny)


ui <- shinyUI(navbarPage(
  "My Application",
  tabPanel("File upload", dataTabUI(
    "tab1",
    csvFileInput("datafile", "User data (.csv format)"),
    "table"
  )),
  tabPanel("Plot", plotTabUI(
    "tab2", basicPlotUI("plot1"), "plotOutput"
  ))

))


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  datafile <- callModule(csvFile, "datafile",
                         stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    datafile()
  })

  plotData <- callModule(basicPlot, "plot1", datafile())

  output$plotOutput <- renderPlot({
    plot(plotData())
  })
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Nice, but the first few functions in your example (esp. `dataTabUI` & `plotTabUI`) are just normal functions that don't really demonstrate any **modules** functionality. In both cases, the call to `ns <- NS(id)` is completely superfluous. It serves no purpose because: (1) the resulting `ns` function is not called anywhere in the function and; (b) there are no corresponding functions used on the server side that takes referenced the namespaced objects that such calls to `ns` would produce. This example would be clearer if it did not include the functions `dataTabUI`, `plotTabUI`, and `dataTab`.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien At least dataTabUI et al. follow the form of a Shiny app and are ready for a dynamic component in the future if needed.

Answer (score 28):

I really like how Matt Leonawicz organises his apps. I took his approach learning how to use Shiny, as we all know it can get quite scattered if not properly managed. Have a look at his structure, he gives an overview of the way he organises the apps in the app called **run_alfresco**

https://github.com/ua-snap/shiny-apps

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion @Pork Chop - is there a good reason why Matt puts the io and reactives in *appSourceFiles* sub directory instead of leaving it in the externals directory?

Comment: @micstr, i guess he adopting structure from larger projects he has done in the past. I would suggest looking at the Visual studio project setup for developing and structuring apps (only for the insight). You mayalso adopt [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) model strucutre in your Rshiny and break it down by folders as he does

Comment: @jangorecki As it was accepted by the user who asked the question I think It did the job, alternatively you can post something, so dont be salty

Comment: Your post is not an answer but a reference to an answer, when the repo will be removed your post will be worthless. You should comment instead. This is how SO is designed to work.

Comment: true, however 4 years have passed and that github account is still there, you really shouldnt vote down legacy questions

Answer (score 8):

I wrote Radiant. I have not heard people say bad things about the code organization (yet) but I am sure it could be better. One option would be to separate the ui and logic as Joe Cheng does in shiny-partials.

https://github.com/jcheng5/shiny-partials

Another might be to try OO programming, e.g., using R6 http://rpubs.com/wch/17459

Comment: A blog post regarding your organization method would be nice. Plus it would allow more conversation regarding shiny app architecture. Everyone benefits if more people are talking/thinking about it

Comment: @MySchizoBuddy I'll see what I can do. Probably won't be very soon however. Teaching two new classes this year.

Comment: did you get any time to write about shiny app organization

Comment: Unfortunately no. I recommend taking a look at [shiny modules](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html). Another option is to create a shiny app as a set of R-packages. That is the approach I now use for [Radiant](https://github.com/radiant-rstats/radiant).

Answer (score 4):

Now there is also the [`golem`](https://github.com/ThinkR-open/golem) package that provides a framework for organising shiny code. It mainly uses modules, but also provides a structure for how to organise e.g. helper functions and css/javascript files. There is also an [accompanying book](https://engineering-shiny.org/).

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I created this solution but I've finally made my work at Roche and Genentech Open Source. When we were working on a big shiny application we were not able to use shiny modules (If I remember correctly because modules did not allow us to share data), and I came up with a component-based architecture inspired mostly by AngularJS.

The repo for the project called Battery is available at [Genentech organization on GitHub](https://github.com/Genentech/battery).

And here you can read a tutorial that explains how to use the framework.

[Architecture for Non-Trivial R Shiny Applications](https://jcu.bi/battery-dev)

Comment: Really nice! Github link is broken.

Comment: @MikaelJumppanen what do you mean it's broken?

Comment: if I click link it says: Page not found. Maybe it is not public repository?

Comment: @MikaelJumppanen Ah, that's right, thanks for spotting that. I need to contact people that approved the project to see if I can make it public. I'm not sure if I can make it myself.

Comment: @MikaelJumppanen the repository is public finally. Thanks for your help.