# Shiny Module that calls a reactive data set in parent Shiny server

Tags: r, module, shiny

I'm looking to port some older Shiny apps to use Shiny Modules, but running into trouble trying to port over my reactive expressions.

According to the [documentation](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html):

> The goal is not to prevent modules from interacting with their
>   containing apps, but rather, to make these interactions explicit. If a
>   module needs to use a reactive expression, take the reactive
>   expression as a function parameter.

I have existing reactive expressions that import data from APIs etc. that I would like to pass in, but can't seem to find the syntax.  If I modify the given [Shiny module example](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/module-example.html) below I can get to the same problem.

Could anyone modify the below so that you can pass in the `car_data()` reactive data into the module?  I've tried just about every combination of `isolate` and `car_data/car_data()` I can think of and am stumped :)

I would prefer to not need to call the data within the module itself, as in my case I'm trying to generalise an ETL function applicable to lots of datasets.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

linkedScatterUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)

  fluidRow(
    column(6, plotOutput(ns("plot1"), brush = ns("brush"))),
    column(6, plotOutput(ns("plot2"), brush = ns("brush")))
  )
}

linkedScatter <- function(input, output, session, data, left, right) {
  # Yields the data frame with an additional column "selected_"
  # that indicates whether that observation is brushed
  dataWithSelection <- reactive({
    brushedPoints(data(), input$brush, allRows = TRUE)
  })

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    scatterPlot(dataWithSelection(), left())
  })

  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    scatterPlot(dataWithSelection(), right())
  })

  return(dataWithSelection)
}

scatterPlot <- function(data, cols) {
  ggplot(data, aes_string(x = cols[1], y = cols[2])) +
    geom_point(aes(color = selected_)) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "#66D65C"), guide = FALSE)
}

ui <- fixedPage(
  h2("Module example"),
  linkedScatterUI("scatters"),
  textOutput("summary")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  ### My modification 
  ### making the reactive outside of module call
  car_data <- reactive({
    mpg
    })

  ## This doesn't work
  ## What is the syntax for being able to call car_data()?
  df <- callModule(linkedScatter, "scatters", car_data(),
                   left = reactive(c("cty", "hwy")),
                   right = reactive(c("drv", "hwy"))
  )

  output$summary <- renderText({
    sprintf("%d observation(s) selected", nrow(dplyr::filter(df(), selected_)))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36517069/4222792 Why do you have to make reactive outside module call? Can't it be output of some of your modules? Your dataImportApi could be one module?

Comment: Thanks Mikael. The reason its outside as its for a general module for use in a package, and I'd like to pass any reactive dataframe into it, not just one particular API call.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Drop the parens after car_data:

```
df <- callModule(linkedScatter, "scatters", car_data,
                   left = reactive(c("cty", "hwy")),
                   right = reactive(c("drv", "hwy"))
  )
```

The module seems to want "unresolved" reactives. The parentheses "resolves" them.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to pass input which is not part of the module just wrap it around `reactive()` as stated in a [tutorial](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html).

> If a module needs to access an input that isn’t part of the module,
>   the containing app should pass the input value wrapped in a reactive
>   expression (i.e. reactive(...)):
>   `callModule(myModule, "myModule1", reactive(input$checkbox1))`

**Update:**
As correctly stated in another answer and [Joe Cheng](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/UzAjSytbfU8) correct way to pass reactive expression is without brackets `()`

`callModule(linkedScatter, "scatters", car_data)`

One option is also to modularize your API input function so you don't need to define reactive expression outside modules. Example of modularized input can be found from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36517069/4222792). 
Below your code with right answer.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

linkedScatterUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)

  fluidRow(
    column(6, plotOutput(ns("plot1"), brush = ns("brush"))),
    column(6, plotOutput(ns("plot2"), brush = ns("brush")))
  )
}

linkedScatter <- function(input, output, session, data, left, right) {
  # Yields the data frame with an additional column "selected_"
  # that indicates whether that observation is brushed
  dataWithSelection <- reactive({
    brushedPoints(data(), input$brush, allRows = TRUE)
  })

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    scatterPlot(dataWithSelection(), left())
  })

  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    scatterPlot(dataWithSelection(), right())
  })

  return(dataWithSelection)
}

scatterPlot <- function(data, cols) {
  ggplot(data, aes_string(x = cols[1], y = cols[2])) +
    geom_point(aes(color = selected_)) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "#66D65C"), guide = FALSE)
}

ui <- fixedPage(
  h2("Module example"),
  linkedScatterUI("scatters"),
  textOutput("summary")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
data(mpg)
  ### My modification 
  ### making the reactive outside of module call
  car_data <- reactive({
    mpg
    })

  ## Fix This doesn't work by reactive (var) no brackets()
  ## What is the syntax for being able to call car_data()?
  df <- callModule(linkedScatter, "scatters", reactive(car_data),
                   left = reactive(c("cty", "hwy")),
                   right = reactive(c("drv", "hwy"))
  )

  output$summary <- renderText({
    sprintf("%d observation(s) selected", nrow(dplyr::filter(df(), selected_)))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked but as Joe Cheng himself confirmed the accepted answer is "the way".

Comment: @MarkeD Oh true. Yes, it has to be like that. car_data is already reactive. I will fix also this answer.