# pass renderUI input from one Shiny module to another

Tags: r, module, shiny

I am trying to modularize Shiny code, for uploading CSV file as input into scatterD3 plot. Additional UI control will be from renderUI to change the x-variable and y-variable. It is just a small modification from the Mikael Jumppanen answer from  [How to organize large R Shiny apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27080089/how-to-organize-large-r-shiny-apps), but I've struggling and cannot get this last bit to work.

For this dataset, I am using the mtcars dataset https://gallery.shinyapps.io/066-upload-file/_w_469e9927/mtcars.csv

```
## load libraries
library(shiny)
library(stringr)
library(scatterD3)

#source("/Users/echang/scratch/tmp/MSD_D3scatter/csvFile_Module.R")
csvFileInput <- function(id, label="CSV file") {
  ## Create namespace
  ns<-NS(id)
  tagList(
    uiOutput(ns("controls"))
  )
}

csvFileControl <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    column(width=3, uiOutput(ns("ColName"))),
    column(width=3, uiOutput(ns("ColEntry")))
  )
}

csvFileUI <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    uiOutput(ns("csvTable"))
  )
}

## server module
csvFile <- function(input, output, session, stringsAsFactors) {
  ns <- session$ns
  ## to reuse namespace, session must be first!!!

  ## User selected file
  userFile <- reactive({
    # If no file is selected, don't do anything
    validate(need(input$file, message = FALSE))
    input$file
  })

  dataframe <- reactive({
    read.csv(
      userFile()$datapath,
      header = input$header,
      sep=input$sep,
      quote = input$quote,
      stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors
    )
  })
  # We can run observers in here if we want to
  observe({
    msg <- sprintf("File %s was uploaded", userFile()$name)
    cat(msg, "\n")
  })

  output$controls <- renderUI({
    ## use taglist to keep everything together
    tagList(
      fileInput(ns('file'), 'Choose CSV file', 
                accept=c('txt/csv','text/comma-separated-values,text/plain','.csv')),
      checkboxInput(ns('header'), 'Has heading', TRUE),
      radioButtons(ns('sep'),'Separator', c(Comma=',',Semicolon=';',Tab='\t'), ','),
      selectInput(ns('quote'),'Quote', c(None ='','Double Quote'='"','Single Quote'="'"),'"')
    )
  })

  ## use renderUI to display table
  output$csvTable <- renderUI({
    output$table <- renderDataTable(dataframe())
    dataTableOutput(ns("table"))
  })

  ## Column Name
  output$ColName <- renderUI({
    df <- dataframe()
    if (is.null(df)) return(NULL)
    items=names(df)
    names(items)=items
    tagList(
      selectInput(ns("xvar"), "Column Names", items),
      selectInput(ns("yvar"), "Column Names", items)
    )
  })

  ## Column Entry
  output$ColEntry <- renderUI({
    df <- dataframe()
    if (is.null(input$col)) return(NULL)
    tagList(
      selectInput(ns("entry"), "Entry Names", df[,input$xvar])
    )
  })

  # Return the reactive that yields the data frame
  return(dataframe)

}## End of module


## scatterD3 module -------------------------------------------------------------

D3scatterUI <- function(id){
  ns<-NS(id)
  tagList(
    scatterD3Output(ns("scatterplot1"))
    )
}

D3scatter <- function(input,output,session,data,xvar,yvar){
  ns <- session$ns

  output$scatterplot1 <- renderScatterD3({
    #scatterD3(data = data, x=mpg, y=carb,
    scatterD3(data = data, x=xvar, y=yvar,
              labels_size= 9, point_opacity = 1,
              #col_var=cyl, symbol_var= data$Assay,
              #lab= paste(mpg, carb, sep="|") , lasso=TRUE,
              #xlab= "IFN-γ", ylab= "IL-10",
              #click_callback = "function(id, index) {
              #  alert('scatterplot ID: ' + id + ' - Point index: ' + index) 
              #  }", 
              transitions= T)
  })
}


## Shiny ######################################################################
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Upload"),

  tabsetPanel(type="tabs",
    tabPanel("tab1",
      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(csvFileInput("basic")),
        mainPanel(csvFileUI("basic"))
        )
      ),
    tabPanel("tab2",
      tagList(
        fluidRow(csvFileControl("basic")),
        fluidRow(D3scatterUI("first"))
        )
      )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  ## Option 1. CSV uploaded file
  datafile <- callModule(csvFile, "basic", stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 

  ## Option 2. mtcar data loaded at start
  #datafile <- reactive({mtcars}) ## data loaded at runApp()
  #callModule(csvFile, "basic") 

  xvar <- reactive(input$xvar) 
  yvar <- reactive(input$yvar)

  callModule(D3scatter, "first", datafile(), xvar, yvar)

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I also consulted the Shiny module design from https://itsalocke.com/shiny-module-design-patterns-pass-module-input-to-other-modules/

I watched the webinar but am unable to get the logic right in my head. https://www.rstudio.com/resources/webinars/understanding-shiny-modules/ Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: The question is pretty clear, why isn't it working even though he has approached the module design as described. Not many people do this yet, so there is not a lot of code examples on how to to it.

Comment: sorry about that! Was a bit flustered when I posted this quesstions. The ask is to get help on refactoring the code so that scatterD3plot will be responsive to changing `xvar` and `yvar`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, this was indeed a bit difficult, as working with modules is not exactly straightforward. You were close... your main problem was not packing up **all** of the reactives in a list and passing them to where they were needed.

I made the following changes:

1. `csvFile`: declared additional reactive functions `xvar` and `yvar` in the `csvFile` server module function similarly to what you had already done for `dataframe`.
2. `csvFile`: packed all the needed reactives up as a list and returned it as the return value as described in the design pattern link in your post. (Thank you Steph Locke).
3. `server`: passed that list down in the `callModule(D3scatter,... )`, again as described in that link.
4. `D3scatter`: refactored a bit by making the call to `scatterD3` to use vectors extracted from the specified dataframe. This is because I couldn't get it to work with strings as column specifiers (but there is surely a way somehow).

Here are the changed code parts from above:

## csvFile server module

```
csvFile <- function(input, output, session, stringsAsFactors) {
  ns <- session$ns
  ## to reuse namespace, session must be first!!!

  ## User selected file
  userFile <- reactive({
    # If no file is selected, don't do anything
    validate(need(input$file, message = FALSE))
    input$file
  })

  dataframe <- reactive({
    read.csv(
      userFile()$datapath,
      header = input$header,
      sep=input$sep,
      quote = input$quote,
      stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors
    )
  })
  # We can run observers in here if we want to
  observe({
    msg <- sprintf("File %s was uploaded", userFile()$name)
    cat(msg, "\n")
  })

  xvar <- reactive({input[[ "xvar" ]] })
  yvar <- reactive({input[[ "yvar" ]] })

  output$controls <- renderUI({
    ## use taglist to keep everything together
    tagList(
      fileInput(ns('file'), 'Choose CSV file', 
                accept=c('txt/csv','text/comma-separated-values,text/plain','.csv')),
      checkboxInput(ns('header'), 'Has heading', TRUE),
      radioButtons(ns('sep'),'Separator', c(Comma=',',Semicolon=';',Tab='\t'), ','),
      selectInput(ns('quote'),'Quote', c(None ='','Double Quote'='"','Single Quote'="'"),'"')
    )
  })

  ## use renderUI to display table
  output$csvTable <- renderUI({
    output$table <- renderDataTable(dataframe())
    dataTableOutput(ns("table"))
  })

  ## Column Name
  output$ColName <- renderUI({
    df <- dataframe()
    if (is.null(df)) return(NULL)
    items=names(df)
    print(items)
    names(items)=items
    tagList(
      selectInput(ns("xvar"), "Column Names", items),
      selectInput(ns("yvar"), "Column Names", items)
    )
  })

  ## Column Entry
  output$ColEntry <- renderUI({
    df <- dataframe()
    if (is.null(input$col)) return(NULL)
    tagList(
      selectInput(ns("entry"), "Entry Names", df[,input$xvar])
    )
  })

  rlist <- list(dataframe=dataframe,xvar=xvar,yvar=yvar)
  # Return the reactive that yields the data frame
  return(rlist)

}## End of module
```

## server

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  ## Option 1. CSV uploaded file
  rlist <- callModule(csvFile, "basic", stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 

  ## Option 2. mtcar data loaded at start
  #datafile <- reactive({mtcars}) ## data loaded at runApp()
  #callModule(csvFile, "basic") 

  callModule(D3scatter, "first", rlist)

}
```

## D3scatter

```
D3scatter <- function(input,output,session,rlist){
  ns <- session$ns

  output$scatterplot1 <- renderScatterD3({
    #scatterD3(data = data, x=mpg, y=carb,
    mtdf <- rlist$dataframe()
    x <- mtdf[[rlist$xvar()]]
    y <- mtdf[[rlist$yvar()]]
    scatterD3(x=x,y=y,
              labels_size= 9, point_opacity = 1,
              #col_var=cyl, symbol_var= data$Assay,
              #lab= paste(mpg, carb, sep="|") , lasso=TRUE,
              #xlab= "IFN-γ", ylab= "IL-10",
              #click_callback = "function(id, index) {
              #  alert('scatterplot ID: ' + id + ' - Point index: ' + index) 
              #  }", 
              transitions= T)
  })
}
```

Then it worked:

[image]

Here is all the running code again, in case I forgot a change somewhere, or someone just wants to run it. As an aside it is quite cool the way the scatter plot changes from one plot to another... it morphs continuously with an animation-like effect. Unusual.

### Entire application in one file

```
## load libraries
library(shiny)
library(stringr)
library(scatterD3)

#source("/Users/echang/scratch/tmp/MSD_D3scatter/csvFile_Module.R")
csvFileInput <- function(id, label="CSV file") {
  ## Create namespace
  ns<-NS(id)
  tagList(
    uiOutput(ns("controls"))
  )
}

csvFileControl <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    column(width=3, uiOutput(ns("ColName"))),
    column(width=3, uiOutput(ns("ColEntry")))
  )
}

csvFileUI <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    uiOutput(ns("csvTable"))
  )
}

## server module
csvFile <- function(input, output, session, stringsAsFactors) {
  ns <- session$ns
  ## to reuse namespace, session must be first!!!

  ## User selected file
  userFile <- reactive({
    # If no file is selected, don't do anything
    validate(need(input$file, message = FALSE))
    input$file
  })

  dataframe <- reactive({
    read.csv(
      userFile()$datapath,
      header = input$header,
      sep=input$sep,
      quote = input$quote,
      stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors
    )
  })
  # We can run observers in here if we want to
  observe({
    msg <- sprintf("File %s was uploaded", userFile()$name)
    cat(msg, "\n")
  })

  xvar <- reactive({input[[ "xvar" ]] })
  yvar <- reactive({input[[ "yvar" ]] })

  output$controls <- renderUI({
    ## use taglist to keep everything together
    tagList(
      fileInput(ns('file'), 'Choose CSV file', 
                accept=c('txt/csv','text/comma-separated-values,text/plain','.csv')),
      checkboxInput(ns('header'), 'Has heading', TRUE),
      radioButtons(ns('sep'),'Separator', c(Comma=',',Semicolon=';',Tab='\t'), ','),
      selectInput(ns('quote'),'Quote', c(None ='','Double Quote'='"','Single Quote'="'"),'"')
    )
  })

  ## use renderUI to display table
  output$csvTable <- renderUI({
    output$table <- renderDataTable(dataframe())
    dataTableOutput(ns("table"))
  })

  ## Column Name
  output$ColName <- renderUI({
    df <- dataframe()
    if (is.null(df)) return(NULL)
    items=names(df)
    print(items)
    names(items)=items
    tagList(
      selectInput(ns("xvar"), "Column Names", items),
      selectInput(ns("yvar"), "Column Names", items)
    )
  })

  ## Column Entry
  output$ColEntry <- renderUI({
    df <- dataframe()
    if (is.null(input$col)) return(NULL)
    tagList(
      selectInput(ns("entry"), "Entry Names", df[,input$xvar])
    )
  })

  rlist <- list(dataframe=dataframe,xvar=xvar,yvar=yvar)
  # Return the reactive that yields the data frame
  return(rlist)

}## End of module


## scatterD3 module -------------------------------------------------------------

D3scatterUI <- function(id){
  ns<-NS(id)
  tagList(
    scatterD3Output(ns("scatterplot1"))
  )
}

D3scatter <- function(input,output,session,rlist){
  ns <- session$ns

  output$scatterplot1 <- renderScatterD3({
    #scatterD3(data = data, x=mpg, y=carb,
    mtdf <- rlist$dataframe()
    x <- mtdf[[rlist$xvar()]]
    y <- mtdf[[rlist$yvar()]]
    scatterD3(x=x,y=y,
              labels_size= 9, point_opacity = 1,
              #col_var=cyl, symbol_var= data$Assay,
              #lab= paste(mpg, carb, sep="|") , lasso=TRUE,
              #xlab= "IFN-γ", ylab= "IL-10",
              #click_callback = "function(id, index) {
              #  alert('scatterplot ID: ' + id + ' - Point index: ' + index) 
              #  }", 
              transitions= T)
  })
}


## Shiny ######################################################################
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Upload"),

  tabsetPanel(type="tabs",
              tabPanel("tab1",
                       sidebarLayout(
                         sidebarPanel(csvFileInput("basic")),
                         mainPanel(csvFileUI("basic"))
                       )
              ),
              tabPanel("tab2",
                       tagList(
                         fluidRow(csvFileControl("basic")),
                         fluidRow(D3scatterUI("first"))
                       )
              )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  ## Option 1. CSV uploaded file
  rlist <- callModule(csvFile, "basic", stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 

  ## Option 2. mtcar data loaded at start
  #datafile <- reactive({mtcars}) ## data loaded at runApp()
  #callModule(csvFile, "basic") 

  callModule(D3scatter, "first", rlist)

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you for such clear dissection of the edit! By making the `xvar` and `yvar` as reactives and then returning them in a list, it mirrors very well Steph Locke's use of `as.data.frame(reactiveValuesToList(input))`. This is very educational