# Include library calls in functions?

Tags: r

Is it good practice to include every library I need to execute a function within that function?

For example, my file `global.r` contains several functions I need for a shiny app. Currently I have all needed packages at the top of the file. When I'm switching projects/copying these functions I have to load the packages/include them in the new code. Otherwise all needed packages are contained in that function. Of course I have to check all functions with a new R session, but I think this could help in the long run.

When I tried to load a package twice it won't load the package again but checks it's already loaded. My main question is if it would slow my functions if I restructure in that way?

I only saw that practice once, library calls inside functions, so I'm not sure.

Comment: As much as possible a function should not have global effects, i.e. effects outside the function itself, but loading a package is a global effect so it is undesirable to put that in a function.  Instead it should be specified globally outside the function.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck: that should be an answer. :)

Comment: You could consider putting your functions into a package. That would offer you better control regarding if you want to load other packages or import all or only some functions from them.

Comment: I totally see your point G. Grothendieck. To go one step ahead, I could load the needed librarys and detach them in the function? @Roland I should have a look into that, thanks for the advice

Comment: Detaching them is a global effect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As one of the commenters suggest, you should avoid loading packages within a function since

1. The function now has a global effect - as a general rule, this is something to avoid.
2. There is a **very** small performance hit.

The first point is the big one. As with most optimisation, only worry about the second point if it's an issue.

Now that we've established the principle, what are the possible solution.

1. In small projects, I have a file called `packages.R` that includes all the `library` calls I need. This is sourced at the top of my analysis script. BTW, all my functions are in a file call `func.R`. This workflow was stolen/adapted from a previous SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1434424/203420)
2. If you're only importing a single function, you could use the `::` trick, e.g. `package::funcA(...)` That way you avoid loading the package.
3. For larger projects, I create an R package that handles all necessary imports. The benefit of creating a package is detailed in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1266400/203420) on structuring large R projects.

Comment: Thank you for your insights. I'm going to structure my functions in an internal responsitory, as this project got really messy in the last months.