# Including `library()` or `require()` calls in functions

Tags: r

This question has been asked before ([Include library calls in functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36284811/include-library-calls-in-functions)) but I wonder if there are any new takes on it.

Putting `library()` calls inside functions is something I am often tempted to do. It means the function is slightly more portable; it will run without errors if a colleague copies it into their own project, for example.

The main downside seems to be "global effects", which I guess refers to namespace clashes. Are there other worries?

The alternatives seem to be:

- **Load packages at the top of the script containing the functions.** But how does a colleague who wants to copy the function know which package is required for which function? (I guess the function documentation should cover this?).
- **Build a package**. But the ROI on this may be low for small-scale projects.

Comment: One could also explicitly reference the required package in each function call, i.e., `dplyr::mutate()` instead of just `mutate()`. This would make it easier for a secondary user to tell which functions come from which packages.

Comment: As a nice side effect of jdobres proposal: You only use functions that you really need and don't import a complete package.

Comment: *"It means the function is slightly more portable"* I'd generally advise against including any form of `library()` or `require()` call inside a function. If portability is your goal, roll up your functions in an R package and share that (as per your second alternative). This will make sure that dependencies are properly met. Creating an R package for sharing code may seem like overkill, but I'd argue that the opposite is true. Especially small projects & work benefit from being supplemented by (small) R packages that include all major functions and analysis routines, including documentation.

Comment: Your concerns are entirely justified. And R has  no good, built-in answer for them. That’s why I built a package, [‘box’](https://klmr.me/box/), which fixes these issues by providing a modern module system for R. ‘box’ provides solutions for the (very real!) issues you’ve identified with the existing alternatives.